# How to chain promise to the return of API call using redux-pack in a React and Redux app?

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-redux

I'm getting the error `.then() is not a function` while attempting to write a React app **test** w/ jest/enzyme. I don't think the test code is the problem, but for reference, I am following this [Redux example](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#async-action-creators).

Here's the code that throws the error:

```
return store.dispatch(actions.fetchFiles()).then(() => {
  expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions)
});
```

My client's codebase uses redux-pack and some conventions that I am not familiar with and I'm having a hard time deciphering where the actual promise is being executed and thus how to chain a "then" function when calling it from my test code as shown in the redux example link posted above.

I've tried to do some debug logging and some variations on the syntax, for example, I attempted to call .then directly on `actions.fetchFiles()` since I was under the impression that it was the call that actually returned the promise, but it didn't work. I'm getting a tad lost in all this code and questioning where the promise is actually getting executed/returned.

The basic structure of the code is as follows:

A connected Container component that fetches a list of files from an API and then dispatches.

The actual page works fine, but my attempts to test (like the Redux article referenced above) blow up.

Here are what I believe to be the relevant blocks of code in play:

Container component

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { actions } = this.props;
    actions.fetchUpload();
  }

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ...state.upload,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  actions: bindActionCreators({ 
    ...uploadActions,
  }, dispatch),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UploadContainer);
```

actions.js

```
import api from '../../core/api';

export const FETCH_FILES = 'upload/fetch-files';

const actions = {
  fetchFiles: () => ({
    type: FETCH_FILES,
    promise: api.upload.getFiles()
  })
};

actions.fetchUpload = () => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(actions.fetchFiles());
};

export default actions;
```

reducer.js

```
import { handle } from 'redux-pack';
import { FETCH_FILES } from './actions';

const initialState = {
  files: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_FILES:
      return handle(state, action, { // this is redux-pack syntax
        success: (s, a) => ({ ...s, files: a.payload.files })
      });

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

upload.js (api.upload.getFiles)

```
export default http => ({
  getFiles: () => http.get('/file')
});
```

api.js - uses Axios

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { SubmissionError } from 'redux-form';
import queryString from 'query-string';
import upload from './upload';

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: '/api/',
  withCredentials: true,
  paramsSerializer: params => queryString.stringify(params),
});

class HttpError extends Error {
  constructor(status, error, errors = {}) {
    super(`Http Error: ${status}`);
    this.status = status;
    this.error = error;
    this.errors = errors;   
  }

  getReduxFormError = defaultError => new SubmissionError({
    _error: this.error || defaultError,
    ...this.errors,
  });
}

const handleUnauth = (method, url, options) => (err) => {
  const { status } = err.response;

  if (status === 401) {
    return axios.get('/users/refresh')
      .then(() => method(url, options))
      .catch(() => Promise.reject(err));
  }

  return Promise.reject(err);
};

const handleHttpError = (err) => {
  const { status, data: { message = {} } } = err.response;
  if (typeof message === 'string') {
    return Promise.reject(new HttpError(status, message));
  }

  return Promise.reject(new HttpError(status, null, message));
};

const http = {
  get: (url, options) => axios.get(url, options)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(handleUnauth(axios.get, url, options))
    .catch(handleHttpError),
  post: (url, data, options) => axios.post(url, data, options)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(handleUnauth(axios.post, url, options))
    .catch(handleHttpError),
  patch: (url, data, options) => axios.patch(url, data, options)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(handleUnauth(axios.patch, url, options))
    .catch(handleHttpError),
  delete: (url, options) => axios.delete(url, options)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(handleUnauth(axios.delete, url, options))
    .catch(handleHttpError),
};

export default {
  upload: upload(http)
};
```

I was expecting the tests to pass because the returned object should match the expected actions, but it errors. Here's the full message:

```
FAIL  src/modules/upload/upload.test.js
Upload module actions › Returns an array of files when calling actions.fetchFiles

TypeError: store.dispatch(...).then is not a function
  43 |     // );
  44 |
> 45 |    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchFiles()).then(() => {
     |
  46 |     expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedActions);
  47 |    });
  48 |   });
  at Object.then (src/modules/upload/upload.test.js:45:52)
```

**When/where is the promise getting returned and how can I chain a .then function like the Redux test example linked above?**

Comment: From what I understand you want to dispatch `async` actions, use `redux-thunk` for that.https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: If you look at the docs, `store.dispatch` returns the dispatched action: https://redux.js.org/api/store#returns-1. In your case `fetchFiles` returns an object with a `promise` attribute, so you might be able to chain it by doing something like `store.dispatch(actions.fetchFiles()).promise.then(() => {})`

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, I tried that but got the error that .promise was not a function.  

    `TypeError: store.dispatch(...).promise is not a function`  
`    > 45 |    return store.dispatch(actions.fetchFiles()).promise().then(() => {`

Comment: @RohitKashyap, Thanks for the advice. The application is already using `redux-thunk` for async actions in production and it works fine there; however, my **test code** is what's failing and that is using `redux-mock-store` for _testing_ Redux async actions. That said, I still think I am failing to chain my `.then()` to the return of the promise.

Comment: @J2G `promise` is indeed not a function, you should remove the function invocation between `promise` and `then`.

Comment: @PaoloMoretti, removing the invocation of fetchFiles, which _is_ a func that kicks off a series of other nested calls that return a promise somewhere along the way, produces the following error:
`Expected value to equal:                                                                                                             [{"templates": [{"id": 23, "modified": null, "status": "POSTED", "user_id": 10}], "type": "upload/fetch-templates"}]             Received:                                                                                                                            []`